# Login with FR3D LDAP Bundle and FOS User Bundle

Tags: symfony, ldap, fosuserbundle, fr3dldapbundle

First, sorry for my English: I'm French and I don't speak English very well.

I try to login my users in Intranet website on an LDAP directory. So I decided to use FR3D Ldap Bundle and FOS User Bundle on SF 2.0.X.

I have already installed FOSUB and it works fine with a Mysql DB. After, I install FR3D Ldap Bundle => OK.

Now I have a problem with configuration. When I try to log with a user in the FOSUB login form, I have a error message: `"The presented password is invalid."`

This is my security config :

```
 main:
        pattern: ^/                      # ^/ = tout ce qui commence par / = tout notre site
        #fr3d_ldap:  ~
        form_login: # On définit notre méthode d'authentification
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: /annu
            provider:    chain_provider  # On lit l'authentification au provider définit plus haut
            remember_me: true            # On active la possibilité du "Se souvenir de moi" (désactivé par défaut)
        remember_me:
            lifetime: 604800                # in seconds
            key:         %secret%        # On définit la clé pour le remember_me (%secret% est un parametre de parameters.ini)
        anonymous:       true            # On autorise les utilisateurs anonymes (non identifiés)
        logout:   
            path:   /logout
            target: /annu 




providers:
        chain_provider:
            providers: [fos_userbundle, fr3d_ldapbundle]
        in_memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager
        fr3d_ldapbundle:
            id: fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider
```

I don't understand why I can't log my users because I see LDAP request on Wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

You have commented the LDAP Authenticator "#fr3d_ldap:  ~"

You must uncomment it for authentication. The LDAP request which you are seeing on Wireshark are the queries for provide the user.

Symfony requires two step for authenticate a user:

1) Retrieve the user from the repository (query to LDAP Directory)
This step is doing by adding `fr3d_ldap.security.user.provider` to the `providers:` section

2) Authenticate it with his credentials (Bind to LDAP Directory)
This step is doing by adding `fr3d_ldap:  ~` to the `<firewall name:>` section.

Removing the `#` character at the begin of `fr3d_ldap: ~` should fix your issue.